# ASP login sytem (no db)

Tags: authentication, asp-classic

how can i do a simple ASP **login** system which don't uses Database, on some html page? Like scripts, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd assign a cookie server-side upon successful login, then check for the presence of the cookie on each request.

You could use an array for userids and passwords instead of a database on the server for account look-up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example code at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121723/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/050499-1.shtml